# How to filter ListView using a EditText when enter is pressed?

Tags: android, listview, filtering

So, right now, I have the a EditText that filters the data in the ListView as the text is changed. But, I want to change it so that it only filters when the enter key is pressed. I can't seem to figure it out.

It's pulling the data from a database.

```
public class SearchActivity extends NavDrawerActivity {


    private DBHandler dbHelper;
    private SimpleCursorAdapter dataAdapter;
    private EditText myFilter;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        //setContentView(R.layout.activity_main_activity3);

        FrameLayout frameLayout = (FrameLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_frame);
        // inflate the custom activity layout
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View activityView = layoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_main_activity3, null, false);
        // add the custom layout of this activity to frame layout.
        frameLayout.addView(activityView);

        dbHelper = new DBHandler(this);
        dbHelper.open();

        //Clean all data
        dbHelper.deleteAllRecipes();
        //Add some data
        dbHelper.insertSomeRecipes();

        //Generate ListView from SQLite Database
        displayListView();

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    private void displayListView() {

        final Cursor cursor = dbHelper.fetchAllRecipes();

        // The desired columns to be bound
        String[] columns = new String[]{
                //DBHandler.COLUMN_CODE,
                DBHandler.COLUMN_NAME,
                DBHandler.COLUMN_TYPE,
                DBHandler.COLUMN_INGRED
        };

        // the XML defined views which the data will be bound to
        int[] to = new int[]{
                //R.id.code,
                R.id.name,
                R.id.type,
                R.id.ingredient,
        };

        // create the adapter using the cursor pointing to the desired data
        //as well as the layout information
        dataAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                this, R.layout.recipeinfo,
                cursor,
                columns,
                to,
                0);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
        // Assign adapter to ListView
        listView.setAdapter(dataAdapter);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listView, View view,
                                    int position, long id) {
                // Get the cursor, positioned to the corresponding row in the result set
                //Cursor cursor = (Cursor) listView.getItemAtPosition(position);
                Intent n = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), RecipeActivity.class);
                n.putExtra("position", position);
                startActivity(n);
            }
        });

        final EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
                myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

                    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                    }

                    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                                  int count, int after) {
                    }

                    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,
                                              int before, int count) {
                        dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

                    }
                });

        dataAdapter.setFilterQueryProvider(new FilterQueryProvider() {
            public Cursor runQuery(CharSequence constraint) {
                return dbHelper.fetchRecipesByName(constraint.toString());
            }
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this:

```
final EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
myFilter.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
...
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start,int before, int count) {
        dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(s.toString());

    }
});
```

Try below:

```
final EditText myFilter = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.myFilter);
myFilter.setImeActionLabel("Filter",1);
myFilter.setPrivateImeOptions("actionUnspecified");
myFilter.setOnEditorActionListener(new TextView.OnEditorActionListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onEditorAction(TextView textView, int id, KeyEvent keyEvent) {
            if (id == 1 || id == EditorInfo.IME_NULL) {
                dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(textView.getText().toString());
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: this didn't really work for me. When i hit enter, nothing shows up.

Comment: then you have problem on your dataAdapter.getFilter()... because When you click on enter , this function is called

Comment: okay, i check that out. also, is the 's' in the 's.toString()' supposed to be 'textView'?

Comment: i think that is supposed to be (textView.getText().toString) instead of s

Comment: Okay, its working now - that turned out to be the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Set to your edit text android:imeOptions="actionSearch" in xml.

```
myFilter.setOnEditorActionListener(new OnEditorActionListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onEditorAction(TextView v, int actionId,
                    KeyEvent event) {
                  if (actionId == EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_SEARCH) {
                    dataAdapter.getFilter().filter(v.getText.toString());
                }
                return false;
            }
        });
```

Comment: this didn't work either. i got an error about the 'handled' part.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than rely on IME options, why not just add a "Done" button and take the value of your EditText when pressed?  You can still use the TextWatcher to make sure the input is valid and no invalid chars are entered.

Answer (score 0):

no need to create extra filter class . you just keep string from TextWatcher then check that string with your list view data using contain method

```
searchforcategory.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence charSequence, int i, int i1, int i2) {
            getAllCetegory(charSequence.toString());

        }

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable editable) {



        }
    });
```

now just check that string with your data

```
 for(int i=0;i<response.body().getDataList().size();i++){

                    if(response.body().getDataList().get(i).getName().contains(checkString)){


                        productDataLists.add(response.body().getDataList().get(i));

                    }


                }
```